# Format of EC public key exported from Android Keystore

Tags: android, cryptography, keystore, android-keystore, elliptic-curve

I am exporting a public key from the Android Keystore with:

`final byte[] publicKey =((KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry)entry).getCertificate().getPublicKey().getEncoded();`

It works but I cannot figure out what format this exported key is in, Android docs only say that `getEncoded()` returns the public key in its encoded format, which does not mean anything to me. How can I check which format this key is encoded in? Is there a standard?

Comment: `((KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry)entry).getCertificate().getPublicKey().getFormat();` will tell the format of the data that is returned by `getEncoded()`.

Comment: Can you gave example bytes from test ECC certificate?

Comment: Probably a SubjectPublicKeyInfo structure around a X9.62 encoded key (both specified using ASN.1 / DER). You can reload using `KeyFactory` for `"EC"` and X509EncodedKeySpec` as input. Feel free to comment "whut?".